# How can I create this bat file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a bat file to uninstall a program but I cant seem to get it working. These are the two commands I want it to do:

```
-wmic
-product where name="program Name" call uninstall
```

It will run the command WMIC but after that nothing happens and I want that second command to be run after WMIC

How can I make a bat file to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

`start /d "<Directory of WMIC>" WMIC uninstall`

Check for reference: [here](http://www.watchingthenet.com/windows-tip-use-batch-file-to-open-multiple-programs-at-once.html)

Comment: Thanks, so I was able to get it to execute, but it asks me a confirmation of Yes/No. How can I enter 'Y' then make it press enter to continue?

Comment: echo y | cmd_asking_yes_or_no